# STL set find performance

Tags: c++, stl, find, set

How to overwrite operator() inside of class MyNode so that set::find can use, and a sets that stores MyNode*.  Then I try to find pointer in set, whose data field is the same as in given object. The below code does not work as I expected. I set breakpoints in of operator method, but none stopped.

I understand I can define find struct compare{} outside of class MyNode, and then define sets like: 
                   set sets 
This is oK for me. Here I am wondering whether it is possible I can define compare inside of class MyNode.

My code is like:

```
class MyNode {
    std::string data;
public:
  MyNode();
MyNode(std::string str);
MyNode(const MyNode& orig);
virtual ~MyNode();

std::string getData();


bool operator<(const MyNode& node){
    return data<node.data;
}

bool operator<( const MyNode* node){
    return data<node->data;
}
```

};

```
void testset(){
MyNode* node1 = new MyNode("5S");

MyNode* node2 = new MyNode("AH");
MyNode* node3 = new MyNode("AH");
std::cout<<"  "<<node2<<std::endl;
std::set<MyNode*>  sets;
sets.insert(node1);
sets.insert(node2);

std::set<MyNode*>::iterator iter =sets.find(node3);  // I expected node2 can be found, but it does not.. 
if(iter != sets.end()){
    MyNode* no = *iter;
    std::cout<<"find it "<<no<<std::endl;   
}
```

}

Another question is if I only define set like:

```
           set<MyNode>  sets. 
           std::find(sets.begin(), sets.end(), findmethod("aa"))
```

Is this complexity O(N) or O(log N)?

Comment: Searching an element in a `std::set` is O(log N).

Comment: @MarcClaesen it is? The standard requires it be logarithmic to the set size. Using the *algorithm* `std::find` rather than the *container* `std::set<T>::find` is indeed linear, which may be what you meant. Not sure.

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant `std::set<T>::find`. I guess I wasn't specific enough.

Comment: @MarcClaesen yeah, that one is not O(n), it is  O(log(n)) per the standard. The generic `std::find` is going to be O(n) simply because it enumerates via forward-iterator. If searching a set, its obviously better to use `std::set<T>::find` which takes advantage of whatever internal data structure the set uses (usually an RB-tree) for delivering the required logarithmic complexity.

Answer (score 2):

As for the first question: `std::set` doesn't care about `operator()()`; it cares about `operator<()`.

As for your second question: the [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) algorithm, unlike the `std::set<T>::find` method, is O(n).

Comment: I updated class MyNode with operator< method, but it still unable to sets.find() still fails to get node2. Is there any wrong?   sets.find() is O(Log N) no matter typename in set is, while std::find() is O(N)

Comment: Well you're storing a `set<MyNode *>` not `set<MyNode>`. You're going to have to supply your own custom comparator if you want `set` to compare `MyNode *` in a different way.

Comment: Define a comparator, named MyNodeCompare, outside of class MyNode, and init set as "set<MyNode*, MyNodeCompare> sets" works.. But what i want here is to seek solution i can define overwrite operator() inside of class MyNode and declare set<MyNode*> sets, so that sets.find() can work..

Comment: @shijiexu What you're asking for cannot be done unless you implement your own `set` container or modify the existing implementation in some way. As @Frerich already pointed out, `std::set` doesn't use `operator ()` so you can't realistically get the behavior you want just by providing that operator.